# How to merge two Gaussians

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have two multivariate Gaussians each defined by mean vectors and Covariance matrices (diagonal matrices). I want to merge them to have a single Gaussian i.e. I assume there is only one Gaussian but I separated observations randomly into two groups to get two different Gaussians which are not too different than each other.

Since I know the number of observations in each of two Gaussians, combined mean estimation is straight forward : $\frac{n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2}{n_1+n_2}$

But, what about the Covariance matrix?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The question was confusing in the original post, especially the "merging Gaussians" part. Maybe the following paragraph would be a better choice.

I have two sets of observations drawn from two multivariate Gaussians each defined by mean vectors and Covariance matrices (diagonal matrices). I want to merge the observations to have a single sample, and I assume to have another Gaussian (i.e. I assume initially there was only a single Gaussian, and observations were separated into two groups to get two different Gaussians).

Comment: Ok I solved it :)

Since covariance matrix is diagonal we can assume having multiple univariates. And then variance combination is as

mu = (n1*mu1 + n2*mu2) / (n1+n2)

sigma^2 = (((sigma1^2 + mu1^2)*n1 + (sigma2^2 + mu2^2)*n2) / (n1+n2)) - mu^2

ps: I used the equation sigma^2 = E[x^2] - E[x]^2

thanks again

Comment: You could post this as an answer (preferably formatted in $\LaTeX$) and accept it.  This is encouraged by [this discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/policy-on-accepting-my-own-answer)

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not let me to do so since I do not have enough reputation. I was required to wait some time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I solved it :)

Since covariance matrix is diagonal we can assume having multiple univariates. And then variance combination is as

$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2}{n_1+n_2}$$

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{(\sigma_1^2 + \mu_1^2)n_1 + (\sigma_2^2 + \mu_2^2)n_2}{ (n_1+n_2)} - \hat{\mu}^2$$

Here, I used $\sigma^2 = E[x^2] - E[x]^2$

thanks again

Comment: The answer here shows the work:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/how-to-calculate-pooled-variance-of-two-groups-given-known-group-variances-mean

Answer (score 5):

I might be wrong or misinterpreted the question, but trying to reproduce the result in the accepted and upvoted answer, I get a different result:

Let $x \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. From the definition of the variance follows
$$
\sigma^2 = E[x^2] - E[x]^2 = E[x^2] - \mu^2
$$$$
or \quad E[x^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2
$$

Now let $x$ be the random variable defined as the weighted average $x = \frac{n_1x_1 + n_2x_2}{n_1 + n_2}$, where $x_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $x_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ are independent.

We have easily
$$
E[x] = \frac{n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2}{n_1 + n_2} := \mu
$$

By the above formula for $E[x_1^2]$ and $E[x_2^2]$, and since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent ($E[x_1x_2] = E[x_1]E[x_2]$) we have

\begin{align}
E[x^2] 
&= E[(\frac{n_1x_1 + n_2x_2}{n_1 + n_2})^2] \\
&= \frac{1}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} E[n_1^2 x_1^2 + n_2^2 x_2^2 + 2n_1n_2x_1x_2] \\
&= \frac{1}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} (n_1^2 E[x_1^2] + n_2^2 E[x_2^2] + 2n_1n_2E[x_1]E[x_2]) \\
&= \frac{(\sigma_1^2 + \mu_1^2)n_1^2 + (\sigma_2^2 + \mu_2^2)n_2^2 + 2n_1n_2\mu_1\mu_2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} \\
&= \frac{\sigma_1^2 n_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 n_2^2 + (n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2}
\end{align}

We can use this to calculate the pooled variance:
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 &= E[x^2] - E[x]^2 \\
&= \frac{\sigma_1^2 n_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 n_2^2 + (n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} - \mu^2 \\
&= \frac{\sigma_1^2 n_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 n_2^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} + \mu^2 - \mu^2 \\
&= \frac{n_1^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2}\sigma_1^2 + \frac{n_2^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2}\sigma_2^2 
\end{align}

---

**In the multivariate case**, if the covariance matrix is diagonal, we can apply this formula on each dimension separately. Otherwise, let $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Again start with the general definition of the covariance matrix that gives

$$
\Sigma = E[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T]  = E[XX^T] - \mu \mu^T 
$$$$
or \quad E[XX^T] = \Sigma + \mu\mu^T
$$

Let $X$ be the random variable defined as the weighted average $X = \frac{n_1X_1 + n_2X_2}{n_1 + n_2}$, where $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ are independent.

To simplify, let $D = \frac{1}{(n_1 + n_2)^2}$ . We have now

\begin{align*}
E[XX^T]
&= D \cdot E[(n_1X_1 + n_2X_2)(n_1X_1 + n_2X_2)^T] \\
&= D \cdot  E[n_1^2 X_1X_1^T + n_2^2 X_2X_2^T + 2n_1n_2X_1X_2^T] \\
&= D \cdot (n_1^2 E[X_1X_1^T] + n_2^2 E[X_2X_2^T] + 2n_1n_2E[X_1]E[X_2^T]) \\
&= D \cdot (n_1^2 (\Sigma_1 + \mu_1\mu_1^T) + n_2^2 (\Sigma_2 + \mu_2\mu_2^T) + 2n_1n_2\mu_1\mu_2^T) \\
&= D \cdot (n_1^2 \Sigma_1 + n_2^2 \Sigma_2 + (n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^T)
\end{align*}

Finally the pooled covariance matrix is:
\begin{align*}
\Sigma &= E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X]^T \\
&= \frac{n_1^2 \Sigma_1 + n_2^2 \Sigma_2 + (n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^T}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} - \mu\mu^T \\
&= \frac{n_1^2 \Sigma_1 + n_2^2 \Sigma_2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} + \mu\mu^T - \mu\mu^T \\
&= \frac{n_1^2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2}\Sigma_1 + \frac{n_2^2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2}\Sigma_2
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Nice first post!

Comment: Sorry for not much clear question. With merge, I had simply meant that we concatenate (put together) two sets of observations (with sizes $n_1$ and $n_1$) and recalculate mean and variance. So there is no assumption of defining a new variable as the weighted average of the older two. Hence, you simply take the average of $E[x_1^2]$ and $E[x_2^2]$ when calculating new $E[x^2]$. Again, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @ahmethungari I disagree: you give a formula for E[x^2] - E[x]^2 but you never say what "x" is, and it is not obvious. In particular, with your result, x cannot be the intuitive weighted average I used above.

Comment: @JulienD if I take two singleton observations at -1 and 1, i.e. the parameters of the gaussians will be $n_1 = n_2 = 1$, $\sigma_2^2 = \sigma_1^2 = 0$, $\mu_1 = -1$, $\mu_2 = 1$, and join these together using your formula, I get $\sigma^2 = 0$, which is suspicious.

Comment: @JulienD: the formula variance of the new Gaussian distribution is missing power two of the mean mu. Please correct it.

Comment: @ngovanmao fixed.

Comment: @JulienD The formula for the variance seems like it simplifies to just the weighted sum of the two variances divided by the squared sum of the $n$'s because $\frac{(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} - \mu^2 = \mu^2-\mu^2 = 0$, right?

Comment: @OliverDain Yes you are right, I simplified the univariate case and obtained the same result as in ngovanmao's answer. The multivariate case simplifies in the same manner.

Answer (score 2):

Given two multivariate normal distributions $N(\mu_0, \Sigma_0)$ and $N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$, the distribution you want is $N(\mu_f,\Sigma_f)$,

where

$\Sigma_f = \Sigma_1 (\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_0)^{-1}\Sigma_0$

$\mu_f = \Sigma_1 (\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_0)^{-1} \mu_0 + \Sigma_0 (\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_0)^{-1} \mu_1$

This works for any covariance matrices (no need to be diagonal).

Answer (score 2):

As the answer of [JulienD](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2364908/412782) is good. But I would like to rewrite the final formulas in a better way and extend them to many random variables, and want to clarify that the [approved answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453794/412782) is likely not correct.

First, I rewrite the answer of JulienD with few additional steps to give it a better form as follows:

- **Single variate**:
  \begin{align}
  \mu &= E[x] = \frac{n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2}{n_1 + n_2}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
\sigma^2 & = E[x^2] - E[x]^2 \\
& = \frac{\sigma_1^2 n_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 n_2^2 + (n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} - \mu^2 \\
& = \frac{\sigma_1^2 n_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 n_2^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} + \frac{(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} - \mu^2 \\ 
& = \frac{\sigma_1^2 n_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 n_2^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2} + \mu^2 - \mu^2 \\
& = \frac{n_1^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2}\sigma_1^2  + \frac{n_2^2}{(n_1+n_2)^2}\sigma_2^2 
\end{align}

- **Multivariate**:
  \begin{align}
  \Sigma &= E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X]^T \\
  & = \frac{n_1^2 \Sigma_1 + n_2^2 \Sigma_2 + (n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^T}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} - \mu\mu^T \\
  &= \frac{n_1^2 \Sigma_1 + n_2^2 \Sigma_2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} + \frac{(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)(n_1\mu_1 + n_2\mu_2)^T}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} - \mu\mu^T \\
  & = \frac{n_1^2 \Sigma_1 + n_2^2 \Sigma_2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} + \mu\mu^T - \mu\mu^T \\
  &= \frac{n_1^2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} \Sigma_1 + \frac{n_2^2}{(n_1 + n_2)^2} \Sigma_2
  \end{align}

**Another approach** to get a formula of variance or covariance matrix (for multivariate) is that we use the theorem of variance (which can find in many textbooks of statistics, e.g., [Larry Wasserman, All of Statistics, theorem 3.20, page 52](https://www.amazon.sg/All-Statistics-Concise-Statistical-Inference/dp/1441923225), or prove via definition as a similar way as JulienD did):
$$
\mathbb{V}(X+Y) = \mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{V}(Y) + 2 \textbf{Cov}(X,Y)
$$
More generally, for random variables $X_1, X_2,..., X_N$:
$$
\mathbb{V}(\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i^2\mathbb{V}(X_i) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N} a_i a_j \textbf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)
$$

Consider $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i), i=1 \cdots N,$; and they are independent of each other. Hence, the covariances are zero, i.e., $\textbf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0.$
A newly aggregated these Gaussian distributions is defined as a weighted sum:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i X_i=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{n_i}{\sum_{l=1}^{N}n_l} X_i,$$
where $a_i=\frac{n_i}{\sum_{l=1}^{N}n_l}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = 1$.

So, we get the mean and covariance of the aggregated distribution as follows:
$$
\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i \mu_i
$$
\begin{align}
\Sigma &=\mathbb{V}(X)= \mathbb{V}(\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i X_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i^2\mathbb{V}(X_i) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N} a_i a_j \textbf{Cov}(X_i,X_j) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i^2 \Sigma_i + 0 \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i^2 \Sigma_i
\end{align}

Now, look at the answer of [ahmethungari](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453794/412782), it seems the answer is not correct.