# When is the standard deviation of the sample mean (of a normally distributed variable) NOT $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm doing a bit of statistics in Python. My Python's pretty solid, but it's been almost a decade since I finished my maths degree, and I'm struggling a bit with the statistics.

I've got two data sets, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(20, 2^2)$ and $Q \sim \mathcal{N}(70, 7^2)$. I then want a weighted combination of these two sets, called $X'$, drawing 98% of the data from $X$ and the other 2% from $Q$. Using the formulae given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453113/how-to-merge-two-gaussians), we then have $X' \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where:

$$
\mu = (0.98 \times 20) + (0.02 \times 70) = 21\\
\sigma^2 = (0.98 \times (2^2+20^2)) + (0.02 \times (7^2+70^2)) - 21^2 = 53.9
$$

So far so good! (And the results I'm getting from my Python program tie in with my calculations.) But here's where I'm stuck...

I want now to look at the distributions for the sample means, $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{X'}$. I was always taught that, if $A \sim \mathcal{N}(m, s^2)$, then $\bar{A} \sim \mathcal{N}(m, \frac{s^2}{n})$. Setting $n = 1000$, this rule works perfectly for $\bar{X}$: it predicts a mean of 20 and standard deviation of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{1000}} \approx 0.0632455532$. However, for $\bar{X'}$ it predicts a mean of $21$ (correct) but a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\frac{53.9}{1000}} \approx 0.23216373532$ (not correct; Python gives $\approx 0.07$).

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on here?

---

Here's my Python for anyone who's interested:

```
from numpy.random import normal
from numpy import mean, std

X_bar = []
X_dash_bar = []
for _ in range(1000):
  X = list(normal(20, 2, 1000))
  X_dash = list(normal(20, 2, 980))+list(normal(70, 7, 20))
  X_bar.append(mean(X))
  X_dash_bar.append(mean(X_dash))

print("mean(X_bar) = "+str(mean(X_bar)))
print("std(X_bar) = "+str(std(X_bar)))
print("mean(X_dash_bar) = "+str(mean(X_dash_bar)))
print("std(X_dash_bar) = "+str(std(X_dash_bar)))
```

Which outputs:

```
mean(X_bar) = 20.00089792500475
std(X_bar) = 0.06364965544782437
mean(X_dash_bar) = 21.001692387965356
std(X_dash_bar) = 0.06971151733127197
```

Comment: As the previous comment says, $\bar X'$ is not normal, so you cannot use the little trick you have been taught.

Comment: @nicomezi why not? For any random variable $Z$ we have $E(\bar Z)  = E(Z)$ and $V(\bar Z) = V(Z)/n$.

Comment: I had a bad feeling that $\bar{X'}$ wasn't normal. Should have gone with my gut! What I'm trying to do, ultimately, is to find a distribution for $\bar{\Delta} = \bar{X'} - \bar{X}$ so that I can get a confidence interval for $\bar{\delta}$. Is there any sensible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right in interpreting $X'$ as $YQ + (1-Y)X$ where $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p=2/100)$ is independent of $Q$ and $X$, then $X'$ is definitely not normal.  But that is **not** the problem with your calculation.   $X'$ does have mean $pE(Q)+(1-p)E(X) = 21$ and variance $p E(Q^2) + (1-p)E(X^2) - E(X')^2 = 53.9$.  That means the standard deviation of the mean of 1000 draws from $X'$ is $\sqrt{53.9/1000}\approx 0.23$, and the sample standard deviation should be a decent approximation to this.

Indeed,

```
from scipy.stats import norm, bernoulli, tstd
import numpy as np

def draw_n(n):
    y = bernoulli.rvs(0.02, size=n)
    x = norm.rvs(loc=20, scale=2, size=n)
    q = norm.rvs(loc=70, scale=7, size=n)
    return y * q + (1 - y) * x

means = [np.mean(draw_n(1000)) for i in range(10000)]
print(np.mean(means))
print(tstd(means))
```

gives about 21 as the mean and about 0.23 as the SD, as expected.

After seeing your code, what you are calculating is observations of the random variable $Z = (1/1000)( X_1 + \cdots + X_{980} + Q_1 + \cdots + Q_{20})$ where $X_i \sim N(20,4)$ and $Q_i \sim N(70,49)$ are independent.  $Z$ is normal, and the sample sd you get is an estimator of the sd of $Z$ which is $\sqrt{(1/1000)^2(980\times 4 + 20\times 49)}=0.07$, agreeing with your computations.

$Z$ is not equal to the mean of 1000 draws from $0.98X + 0.02Q$ (this mean would have variance $(0.98 ^2 \times 4 + 0.02^2 \times 49)/1000 \approx 0.0039$) : rather it's normal with mean $0.98 \times 20 + 0.02 \times 70$ and variance 
$$ \frac{ 980 \times 2^2 + 20 \times 7^2}{1000^2} = 0.0049$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think we might be talking a bit at cross purposes - although I'm sure it's my fault. $Y$ (as you term it) can be treated as a constant in the problem I'm working on. I'll amend my question just now to include my Python code.

Comment: If you spell out what you mean by a weighted combination, it'll help.  The rv which is X 98% of the time and Q otherwise (as simulated above) is not normal, but the rv $0.02Q+0.98X$ is normal - regardless, both of these have the same mean and sd so so do their sample means.

Comment: I meant $X' = 0.02Q +  0.98X$.

Comment: OK, I think I understood.  Then the problem is that $\overline{(0.02 Q + 0.98X)}_{1000}$ (which you want to know about) and $0.98 \bar{X}_{980} + 0.02 \bar{Q}_{20}$ (which you are calculating observations from) aren't the same thing.  By $\bar B_n$ I mean the mean of $n$ observations of $B$ here.

Comment: I see (I think). So $\bar{X'} \sim \mathcal{N}(21, 0.07^2)$. Then would the following be correct: $\bar{\Delta} = \bar{X'} - \bar{X}$, therefore $\bar{\Delta} \sim \mathcal{N}(1, 0.0069)$?

Comment: No.  I'm still confused about what $X'$ is supposed to be.  The variable $Z$ I wrote down which you are taking observations from is $\sim N(21, 0.07^2)$ but it isn't the mean of anything (it's a linear combination of means of different sizes from $X$ and $Q$, per my last comment), so it's confusing notation to call it $\bar X'$.  Whatever $\bar{X}'$ is, it won't be independent of $\bar X$ so $V(\bar \Delta)$ won't be the same as $V(\bar X') + V(\bar X)$ which is what I'm guessing you've done there.

Comment: I think my notation is getting in the way! Let's say that $Y = 0.98X + 0.02Q$. Then, I think what you've said is that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(21, 0.98 \times 2^2 + 0.02 \times 7^2)$. Am I okay so far? Then what I need to do is find mean distributions for $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ so that I can find the distribution for the _change_ in mean.

Comment: And the conclusion that I've come to is that $\bar{\Delta} \sim \mathcal{N}(1, 0.0089)$. (Apologies, there was a typo above.)

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: No. If $Y = 0.98X + 0.02Q$ then $Y \sim N(21, 0.98^2 \times 2^2+0.02^2 \times 7^2)$ (note the squares).  $\bar Y_n \sim N(21, \sigma^2 / n)$ where $\sigma^2=0.98^2 \times 2^2+0.02^2 \times 7^2$ and $\bar X_n \sim N(20, 2^2/n)$. But you have to be more careful when you compute the distribution of $\bar\Delta$ because $\bar Y$ and $\bar X$ aren't independent.

Comment: Cool. I think I'm getting this. So then, calling ${\sigma_\bar{X}}^2$ the variance of $\bar{X}$ and ${\sigma_\bar{X}}^2$ the variance of $\bar{X}$, would the variance of $\Delta$ be ${\sigma_\bar{X}}^2 + {\sigma_\bar{Y}}^2 - 2\mathrm{Cov}(\bar{X}, \bar{Y})$?

Comment: If so, any tips for calculating $\mathrm{Cov}(\bar{X}, \bar{Y})$? I'm told that $\mathrm{Cov}(\bar{A}, \bar{B}) = \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Cov}(A, B)$, and also that I can use that $Y = 0.98X + 0.02Q$ where $X$ and $Q$ are independent to boil $\mathrm{Cov}(\bar{X}, \bar{Y})$ down to $0.98 \times 2^2$. But this doesn't seem to give me the right answer...

Comment: Yes, $V(A-B) = V(A) + V(B) - 2\operatorname{cov}(A,B)$ in general. If your computations don't match your theory, it may come down to how you are sampling. You want to estimate $V(\bar \Delta) = V(\bar Y - \bar X) = V(\overline(0.98X + 0.02Q) - \bar X)$ by sampling. If so, you need to use the same X-sample to compute both the sample means (for $0.98X+0.02Q$ and for $X$).  But wouldn't it be simpler just to notice $\Delta= 0.02Q-0.02X$?